# Are there Islamic books which can help with anxiety?

Tags: reference-request, self-purification

I suffer from some anxiety.  Are there any books available that can help with this? I have seen "[The Art of Happiness](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594488894)" by the Dalai Lama, but I would like to read something by a Muslim using Islam to help.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you able to say something about your anxiety in a generalised kind of way, ie is it around an aspect of Islam, metaphysical doubt, or family/personal issues (which I'm afraid this site isn't geared up to handling).

Answer (score -2):

I've found [Sufi Essays](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BMNQNOHXKOMC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=maqamat+sufism&source=bl&ots=imM-n9EWnW&sig=h0oaiI5NJ-KQU5OweqmYrn2yFbo&hl=en&ei=_bKZS7O6BZHOsgO2lZyRCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=maqamat%20sufism&f=false) by [Seyyid Hossein Nasr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hossein_Nasr) useful; he writes about the inner spiritual dimension of Islam.

To quote:

> Revelation is limited in its outer form; it is outwardly finite and so appears to men in its rites, doctrines and symbols as one more set of finite forms along with others that surround him in this world. But unlike other forms, the religious and revealed forms open inwardly toward the Infinite.

and

> His finite psyche can remain healthy and sound only when it is in quest of that Beloved the union with whom is the goal of all mystical romances.

He also writes:

> Sufism...in its essence joins the paths of spiritual realization found in other traditions while in its formal aspect it shares the genius and the particular features of Islam.